# I tried to change postgresql md5 to scram-sha-256 and I get FATAL password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I'm using `postgresql` and as part of learning, I tried to change to login methods to have a more secure login methods. e.g. using `scram-sha-256` instead of `md5`. I tried to change my `password_encryption` to `scram-sha256` in `postgresql.conf` file, and changed `pg_hba.conf` METHOD to `scram-sha-256` as well, you can see the changes in the configuration below:

```bash
# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
password_encryption = scram-sha-256     # md5 or scram-sha-256
#db_user_namespace = off
and 

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Then after restarting the server, I try to login using `cmd` when I get following error:

```
C:\Users\amir>psql -U postgres postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I can solve the problem by changing everything to `md5` method and ignoring `password_encryption` in `postgresql.conf` file. How can I resolve this issue? do I have to change the configuration to default then try to create user and assigning an encrypted password for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each user password hash is saved in the table `pg_authid`. It includes the hashing algorithm that is used to transform the password to its hash.

When setting the `password_encryption` in postgresql.conf, you are setting the default encryption, i.e. the one used when creating a user or when (re)setting your password. The table `pg_authid` is **not** updated.

When changing pg_hba.conf, you are saying to accept only passwords hashed using the given method. The table `pg_authid` is **not** updated.

There is an important note in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html):

> To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if
> md5 is specified as a method in pg_hba.conf but the user's password on
> the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based
> authentication will automatically be chosen instead

So the solution is to

1. start with the existing users, md5
2. update postrgres.conf to use scram and reload the configuration
3. reset the user password: it will now be saved as scram in pg_authid
4. you can still use md5 in pg_hba.conf
5. when happy with the move from md5 to scram, update pg_hba.conf to specify scram instead of md5

Answer (score 10):

The best way to upgrade your `postgres` service with a new password encryption is:

**1.** Connect to your server using 'ssh' or open your terminal.

**2.** Change the `password_encryption` parameter

Edit `postgresql.conf` and change `password_encryption` to

```bash
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

**Note:** Make sure you remove the hash `#` at the beginning of the line. Then reload the server by running:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

An alternative is:

```bash
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Another alternative is:

```bash
pg_ctl reload -D <data-dir-path>
```

where `<data-dir-path>` is the PostgreSQL data directory.

Also, you can run this SQL statement using `psql`:

```sql
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

**2.A.** Now switch into the `postgres` user and run `psql`

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql
```

**2.B.** Then, look into the log file to see if the reload was successful, and check the new value via SQL:

```sql
SHOW password_encryption;
```

Note that even though you changed the parameter, the old MD5 passwords still work, as long as the authentication method in `pg_hba.conf` is set to md5.

When setting the `password_encryption` in `postgresql.conf`, you are setting the default encryption, (i.e. the one used when creating a user or when re-setting your password). The table `pg_authid` is not updated.

When changing `pg_hba.conf`, you are saying to accept only passwords hashed using the given method. The table `pg_authid` is also not updated.

**3.** Set passwords again

All password authenticated users have to change their password. In psql, a superuser can change any user’s password with

```sql
\password <user>
```

Even if the user sets the same password as before, the password will now be hashed with `SHA-256`. Before proceeding with the next step, examine the table `pg_authid` and make sure that it contains no more MD5 hashed passwords.

```sql
SELECT
    rolname, rolpassword ~ '^SCRAM-SHA-256\$' AS has_upgraded
FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolcanlogin;
```

This query looks for users that have the `LOGIN` privilege (i.e. they can login to your PostgreSQL cluster) and determines if their password still exists in a `PostgreSQL-style MD5` hash. If `has_upgraded` is `FALSE`, then the user needs to re-hash their password.