# PostgreSQL Random bug with a specific password

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-13

Recently upgraded my PostgreSQL version from 10.x to 13 and i have came across a weird bug related to user authentication while accessing the DB.

These are the old credentials which i was using to connect with PostgreSQL 10.x version-

**root**

**26_v9Fe},,6\Z3E?**

But the same credentials when i created in PostgreSQL v13, i'm getting the well known authentication failure error in Java (using Java code to connect to Postgresql)-

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user root

The only difference in my PostgreSQL version was the encryption type- *md5* was used with the 10.x version but the 13 version is using *scram-sha-256*.

Would be helpful if someone can provide an insight on this.

Comment: In what sense is this random, does it not happen every time?

Comment: my bad, wanted to say strange.
Happens with the postgresql 13 with the above mentioned specific password only.

Comment: Maybe password is ok, but root (remote) password login is not allowed anymore in some default settings? Or would that give a different error message?

Comment: When i change the above mentioned password in pgAdmin and in my Connector.java file, i'm able to connect via updated credentials successfully without any issues.
But when i rollback to the mentioned credentials, the same error message pops up

Comment: You can't upgrade a password from md5 to scram by upgrading the server.  If the password is still in md5 format but the hba now demands scram, that would explain the failure.

Comment: Do you have your password in a Java string literal?

Comment: You do need to set the password again. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64316324/i-tried-to-change-postgresql-md5-to-scram-sha-256-and-i-get-fatal-password-authe/64317399#64317399)

Comment: @jjanes It's a fresh installation of PostgreSQL v13.x [not updated anything], i'm creating a fresh set of credentials via the pgAdmin with the above mentioned username and password.
My issue is if i change the above mentioned password to something else, the connection is successfully established. But with above particular password only i'm unable to establish connection with PostgreSQL 13.x[scram-sha-256].
The older PostgreSQL v10.x[md5] had the same set of credentials and it works.

Comment: @tgdavies yes i'm using it as a string literal

Comment: Are you escaping the \ correctly?

Comment: What version of pgAdmin?

Comment: @tgdavies i mean its put up in as a string. Are there any other alternative to pass on the password and username?

Comment: @jjanes pgAdmin 4 that comes prebundled with default Postgresql 13 installation

Comment: You need to show the exact Java code you have written.